# Why this import is not working

Tags: java, apache, normalization, relative-path, absolute-path

I'm using a the normalize function to get the absolute path from a String,

```
org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.normalize(String)
```

But when I use just `normalize(String)` I get :

> The method normalize(String) is undefined for the type MyClass

I tried : `import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;`

I downloaded the library from Apache website, and linked it to my project but I get the same error.

I don't want to write everytime the whole line to call the function.

Is there any solution for this ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Indigo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Either import the class:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

FilenameUtils.normalize(string);
```

or import the method:

```
import static org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.normalize;

normalize(string);
```

And if you are using Eclipse, just press Ctrl-shift-M to import what your cursor is at.
Also autocompleting classnames should add imports.

Answer (score 1):

keep the import as `import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;`
and invoke the method as `FilenameUtils.normalize(string)`.

or change the import to `import static org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.normalize;`
and leave the method invocation as it is (`normalize(string)`).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a static method. You need to keep the import there and then call:

```
FilenameUtils.normalize(String);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type FileNameUil and then press ctl + space u. select org. Apace.common.io your eclpse or intelliJ would auto add import statement then select Normalize